# Como instalar o IONIC com Android no Mac OSX

Tags: ionic, osx, android-sdk

Eu estou tentando instalar o Android no Mac OSX para iniciar meus estudos em Desenvolvimento de Apps.

Eu instalei com sucesso o NPM, Cordova e IONIC. Também baixei o Android Studio e baixei algumas versões do Android SDK.

Agora me falta configurar o ambiente para conseguir rodar o comando:

```
ionic add platform android
```

Eu ja tentei de diversas maneiras, por diversos tutoriais, mas ainda estou vendo o seguinte erro:

[image: Imagem do Erro]

Alguém pode me ajudar a configurar? Grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo que você ja faz as instalações que voce disse Nodejs, cordova, e ionic ainda resta você fazer algumas instalações e configurações.

Seguindo a sequencia:

Instale o Git! http://git-scm.com/downloads

Instale o Bower!  npm install bower -g ou sudo npm install bower -g

Instale o Grunt! npm install gulp -g ou sudo npm install gulp -g

E para seguir instale o seu editor de codigo preferido (Sublime Text :)).

Para conferir se tudo esta ok rode o comando "ionic info" sem as aspas e confira se nao retorna nenhum erro!

Logo na sequencia prepare as variaveis de ambiente! Para Android siga ( http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_ platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20)
Para iOS siga (h t tp://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_ platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20)

feito isso tudo voce ja pode exportar um projeto Hello World para iniciar os estudos, seguindo esse comando voce consegue criar uma aplicação Ionic em seu ambiente!

**ionic start -a "Example 1" -i app.example.one example1 blank**

Caso queira algo mais incrementado par aprender apenas toque o blank do comando por tabs ou sidemenu para gerar apps com um template com mais recursos um com Abas e outros com Menu Lateral.

Proximo passo é testar a aplcação primeiramente no browser e conferir o funcionamento execute dentro da pasta criada do seu projeto "ionic serve" sem aspas é claro, que isso ira abrir o seu navegador e executando a sua aplicação criada.

Feito isso i sim pode começar a adicionar plataformas e testar em dispositivos reais e tambem em emuladores segue o comando para adicionar a plataforma Android ao seu projeto

**ionic platform add android** (esse é o comando correto e nao da forma indicada na pergunta)

na sequencia para testar no emulador.

**ionic emulate android**